# Why wont AWS send the SMS verification code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, sms, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS to have users sign up in my app. The users enter their phone number and a password and a code should be sent to the user. You can see in the below screenshot that 2 users have been created in Cognito, but no SMS ever arrives. I'm using UK phone numbers (none in the USA).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help explain why and how i can get SMS's to come through??

Comment: Have you setup SMS messaging support in your Cognito user pool yet? Per  these instructions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-sms-settings.html On the page in your screenshot you should click over to the "Messaging" tab and see if SMS is setup. Please read the full documentation I linked, there is a process for moving your SNS account of out sandbox mode before it can actually send SMS messages.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for the advice. I didn't spot that, but it looks like that isn't setup. I did go through the instructions and there is already an IAM assigned and a region. I even went through to create an inline policy for the IAM, still see the glaring red tirangle. Any ideas?

Comment: There's a lot more to it than just an IAM policy and an SNS resource policy. That part just allows Cognito to send stuff to SNS, you still need to configure SNS to be able to send SMS messages. There's quite a few steps, documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-phone-number-as-subscriber.html

Comment: @MarkB is this true even if you want to AWS to just generate and send a one time passcode (OTP) to users signing up for the first time or have forgotten password? There's no other use case i have. I know for email its automatic, OTPs are sent with no other configuration necessary.

Comment: Yes it doesn't matter. Cognito offers a default email configuration without requiring you to setup Amazon SES, but it does not offer a default SMS configuration.